# How to jump to the end of quoted string, considering escaped delimiters

Tags: cursor-movement, syntax-highlighting

Assuming the following situation

```
$someVar = "Some String with \"escaped\" inner delimiters";
```

with the cursor somewhere in the double-quote delimited string.

What is the quickest way to jump to the final (actually delimiting) double quote? I can only think of `3f"`/`f"` depending on where the cursor is, or even using a negative lookbehind with `/`, but there has to be a better way?

Is there perhaps even something like "jump to the end of the current syntax-highlighted block"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Kent's solution assumes a single string in the line. Another approach is (mis-)using the *a / inner quoted string* text object (`a"` / `i"`), through visual mode:

- `va"<Esc>`    for `:set selection=inclusive` (default)
- `vi"<Esc>`    for `:set selection=exclusive`

@Kent's solution also doesn't work as a single, atomic `{motion}`, so you cannot use it after commands like `d` or `y`. That can be done via the [vim ninja feet plugin](https://github.com/tommcdo/vim-ninja-feet) as `d]i"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$F"
```

This goes to the end of the line, and searches backwards for `"`.